# R min function is not returning minimum value

Tags: r, function, min

first time posting on here and would really appreciate the help. 
I am doing the R programming assignment on the Data Science specialization on Coursera but am struggling with one part.

```
best <- function(state, outcome) {
  directory <- setwd("/Users/SParikh3/Desktop/rprog-data-ProgAssignment3-data")
  data <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
  table <- data.frame(cbind(data[,2], data[,7], data[,11], data[,17],   data[,23]))
  colnames(table) <- c("Hospital", "State", "Heart Attack", "Heart Failure", "Pneumonia")

  if(!state %in% table[,"State"]){
    stop("Invalid state")
  }
  else if (!outcome %in% c("Heart Attack", "Heart Failure", "Pneumonia")) {
    stop("Invalid outcome")
  }
  else {
    table <- subset(table, State == state, select = c(outcome, "Hospital"))
    x <- as.numeric(table[,outcome])
    minimum <- min(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    result <- table[, "Hospital"][which(x == minimum)]
    output <- result[order(result)]
  }
  return(output[1])
}
```

This is my code and for some reason, the minimum value is not returning the correct minimum value. It works when I choose Heart Attack but not for the other outcomes. For example, if the min value for Heart Failure is 5 it returns something like 7. Any reason why this may be happening? Please let me know! Thank you!

Comment: I think your columns are all `factor`s from the `data.frame(cbind(..` step, as `cbind` converts it to a `matrix` and matrix can hold only a single class. change it to `data.frame(data[,2], data[,7], data[,11], data[,17],   data[,23])` or concisely `table1 <- data[c(2,7,11,17,23)]`  and see if that works.  Here I changed the `table` to `table1` as table is a function.

Comment: Whoever taught you the `data.frame(cbind(...))` paradigm should be summarily ... loss for words ... what can I say that conveys an extreme sanction that doesn't involve unacceptable violence?

Comment: I just figured it out. I had to go in and order my outcome with as.numeric(as.character())....

Why is the data.frame(cbind( so horrible?

Comment: Because of what `akrun` says above. `cbind` happens first, which converts your data to a matrix, which turns everything into the same class, which often causes bugs. In most cases, `data.frame(...)` works well, and `data.frame(cbind(...))` works poorly. The only thing `cbind()` does in (most) `data.frame(cbind(...))` calls is add problems.